# Excluding current entry on related entries

Tags: forloop

I'm trying to exclude the current entry for a set of related entries. I am targeting an entry field to grab the set of related entries. Here is the code I have:

```
   {% if block.relatedPageEntries | length %}
      {% for entry in block.relatedPageEntries.all() %}
      {% set related = craft.entries({
        section:        'general',
        orderBy:         'title',
        relatedTo:       entry,
      }).id('not ' ~ entry.id) %}

      {% if related %}
      {% for entry in related %} ... {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
     
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

I am trying to use .id('not ' ~ entry.id) to exclude the current entry but that isn't working. I believe that it's because it's in the current for loop.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a different variable name for the entry in the inner loop, so that the `entry` variable in the outer loop is not overwritten

```
{% if block.relatedPageEntries | length %}
  {% for entry in block.relatedPageEntries.all() %}
    {% set related = craft.entries({
      section: 'general',
      orderBy: 'title',
      relatedTo: entry,
    }).id('not ' ~ entry.id) %}

    {% if related %}
      {% for relatedEntry in related %}
        ... do something with relatedEntry ...
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In this modified code, the `entry` in the inner loop is named relatedEntry, so the `entry`.`id` `value` being used in the `id('not ' ~ entry.id)` filter still refers to the outer `loop`'s entry variable.

Comment: Thank you for that code. Unfortunately, this changes the output so that only the current page entry info is shown. So all selections show the same parent title, url etc. 
I am targeting another pages' field of related entries if that makes any difference.